# How import text to Prometheus monitoring

Tags: prometheus

I would like to know if is it possible to monitor a text file through Prometheus, anybody knows?
This file will be fed by the Linux system by a script.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try:

- [Textfile collector from Prometheus node exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter#textfile-collector)
- [Grok exporter](https://github.com/fstab/grok_exporter)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, I could monitor the text file using textfile collector.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Bash script and push it to Prometheus using [PushGatewaybatch](https://medium.com/avmconsulting-blog/pushing-bash-script-result-to-prometheus-using-pushgateway-a0760cd261e)

In bash script calculate or check hash code of file. First save md5 in a file (Linux):

```
md5sum file1.txt file2.csv > myfiles.md5
```

and then check it in script:

```
md5sum -c myfiles.md5
```

If file be changed, the result will be different.